# notifying @channel in slack via azure logic app

Tags: azure, slack, azure-logic-apps

I tried notifying the user in a channel using user ID (for eg. hey <@U123456|bob>, how are you?). here **@U123456** is the user ID.
This is getting notified by the user.

But when i try to notify <@C123456|channel>, its not notifying. here **@C123456** is the channel ID and **channel** is the default tag that is used to notify all the users in that channel.

@channel is used to notify all the users in a particular channel. I am failing at it.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been resolved,

<@C1234567> isn't a valid way to notify a channel, instead use **`<!channel>`** within that channel to trigger a notification.

https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#variables

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the actual channel name instead of the default channel tag?

<@C123456|**REALCHANNELNAME**>